# CSS Only Slider with Fixed elements

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to create the following layout without adding containers? 
The fixed elements are non-scrollable, and the scrollable slides to left and right.

Layout:

```
 -------------------------------------------------------

|  Fixed | Fixed < Scrollable | Scrollable | Scrollable >

 -------------------------------------------------------
```

Markup:

```
<section class="fixed">
    <h3>Item1</h3>
</section>
<section class="fixed">
    <h3>Item2</h3>
</section>
<section class="scrollable">
    <h3>Item2</h3>
</section>
<section class="scrollable">
    <h3>Item2</h3>
</section>
<section class="scrollable">
    <h3>Item2</h3>
</section>
```

Comment: without adding containers - does this mean that you can't modify the html?

Comment: I don't understand what exactly you are trying to achieve.

Comment: can i assume that you don't mean fixed as in the css `position` property? and scrollable perhaps means using the `overflow` property?

Comment: @Pete yes, without changing the html.

Comment: @JonasGrumann I got several blocks that are non-moving and right of them a slider containing elements. I am asking whether it is possible to lay this out without adding to the markup.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean somthing like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/jLjxG/). If is so, you have to add the following css.

```
section {
    display:inline-block;
}

.fixed {
    width: 80px;
}

.scrollable {
    overflow-x:scroll;   
    width: 80px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Let me clarify:
1. The fixed elements' size vary (and so does the scrollables)
2. The scrollable elements are sliding left or right together. giving overflow-x:scroll to each element will not achieve the required behavior.

Comment: I don't think it is possible to make them scroll together if you can't use javascript or add a container around them